# How to check if Button is still clicked after second

Tags: java, android

I am looking for a way to call a function when a button is pressed and held for one second. When the button is released another function should be called.

I was thinking about an onLongClickedListener but this won't work well for me since the text that is going to be displayed would stay too long or short.
I am thinking a TouchListener could help me because the Action_Up event would give me the option to let the text dissapear when the button isn't pressed anymore. The Action_down event gives me when the button is pressed and I thought I could start a timer when the button is pressed, wait a second, check again if the button still is pressed and then call the function (show the text).

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (v.getId()) {
    // the button. I set bFertig.setOnTouchListener(this); in onCreate
    case R.id.bFertig:
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            // everything works up to here
            waitTimerNotif = new CountDownTimer(1000, 500) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long arg0) {}

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    // here im checking if the button still is pressed
                    if (bFertig.isPressed()) {
                        // It never goes into here
                        ShowNotifBox("Fertig", "fertig", false, false,false);
                    }
                }
            }.start();
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            DissapearNotifBox();
            Log.d("Debug", "Button released");
        }
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

For the Button in xml:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/bFertig"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/fertigbutton"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="18.5dp" 
    android:clickable="true"/> <!--Googleing suggested I need this for isPressed() to work but it didnt help
```

Any ideas what I did wrong or why this isnt working? Thanks!

Comment: Didn't read all of this code, but couldn't you set a time when you start touching, and then compare that with the time when you releasE?

Comment: longClickListener is really how you should do it, since it will use the standard delay used by all other applications in the user's system

Comment: @Cruncher don't quite understand what you mean. I don't want the function to be called after the button was released but rather one second after the button is first pressed down until the button is released

Comment: Did you try isSelected() instead?

Comment: you can also check again `event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` instead of isPressed()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're returning true, which tells the system that you are handling the touch events, which means the button is not, which means it's probably not updating its pressed state. Try returning false.

Comment: WOW! That really was the Problem. Thanks @Ootinii! Any idea on how I could check if the finger still is on the button or has moved away? Should work with `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` and an `if` like http://goo.gl/XWxsHz but I can'figure out what to replace the rect with.

Comment: Are you implementing the onTouch on the button itself?

Comment: Assuming that you are implementing the touch listener on the button view, you should be able to check if event.getX() >= v.getLeft() && event.getX() <= v.getRight(), event.getY() >= v.getTop() && event.getY() <= v.getBottom(), you would check these on the ACTION_UP event.

Comment: Accept answer, plz :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the `setOnLongClickListener` function?
This should solve your issue.
An example can be find here: [setOnLongClickListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13470404/setonclicklistener-and-setonlongclicklistener-call-on-single-button-issue)

Comment: I know how to use OnLongClickListener but the problem with it is, that I want another function to be called when the button is released. I tried having a LongClickListener start my first function and a onTouchListener which gets when the button is released and then starts the second funktion to hide the text from the first function.